# Reading Google docs spreadsheet

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api

Is it possible to pull rows from a Google Docs spreadsheet using PHP?

In SQL I would use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'value' LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way to do this? I've heard you are supposed to use a 'Zend' framework, but I haven't been able to figure that out either. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Zend_Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html#zend.gdata.spreadsheets.listfeeds.sq) documentation:

```
<?php
  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
  $query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
  $query->setWorksheetId($worksheetId);
  $query->setSpreadsheetQuery('name=John and age>25');
  $listFeed = $spreadsheetService->getListFeed($query);
?>
```

And [to setup the `$spreadsheetService` object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html#zend.gdata.spreadsheets.listspreadsheets):

```
<?php
  $service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
  $spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
  $feed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
?>
```

You'll need to download either the full [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/download/overview), or the standalone [Google Data](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata) library.

Comment: I'm getting a errorFatal error: Class 'Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery' not found in

Comment: Looks like you got some good answers from your other post, just make sure the 'Zend' directory is in your include path, then do `require_once('Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets/ListQuery.php')`. Same goes for the other classes. Or just use the autoloader.

Answer (score 6):

**What you're looking for is the [Google Visualization API Query Language](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage.html#Format)**

No need for PHP middleware to get it working. It's already built-in to docs.

Here's a [brief introduction tutorial](http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/) to help get you started.

It's a SQL-like syntax that works by sending the query through a parameterized URI. It can return the matching data in JSON, CSV, or a HTML Table. It's still really new and has a few quirks so be sure to read through all the comments on the second link I posted.